# MeasureCharacterRanges doesn't fit the character?

Tags: c++, text, fonts, gdi+

I try to measure the region enclosing each character in a string with this code:

```
void Draw(HDC dc)
{
    using namespace Gdiplus;
    Graphics graphics(dc);
    wstring chars;
    for(int i=32; i<127; ++i)
    {
        chars += i;
        chars += 32;
    }

    Font font(L"Times New Roman", 30, FontStyleRegular, UnitPoint);
    TextRenderingHint hint = TextRenderingHintAntiAlias    ;
    const StringFormat* pStringFormat = StringFormat::GenericTypographic();
    StringFormat MeasureFormat(pStringFormat);
    const float Offset = 60.f;
    RectF   layout(Offset, Offset, m_ScreenWidth - Offset*2, m_ScreenHeight - Offset*2);
    std::vector<RectF> charSize;
    for(size_t i=0; i<chars.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            CharacterRange range(i, 1);
            MeasureFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(1, &range);
            Region region;

            graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(chars.c_str(), -1, &font, layout, &MeasureFormat, 1, &region);
            RectF rec;
            region.GetBounds(&rec, &graphics);   
            charSize.push_back(rec);
        }
    }

    graphics.SetTextRenderingHint(hint);

    for(size_t i=0 ; i<charSize.size(); ++i)
    {
        graphics.FillRectangle(&SolidBrush(0xaa998844), charSize[i]);
    }

    graphics.DrawString(chars.c_str(), -1, &font, layout, pStringFormat, &SolidBrush(0xff0000ff));
}
```

and this is the result:

[image: screen shot]

As you can see the regions for letter 'f' and 'g' doesn't enclose those characters perfectly. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because those characters are designed to overhang with the adjacent characters.  The widths you're highlighting are how far over the next character should start, which is not necessarily the bounding box of the character.

I'm not an expert in GDI+, but you probably need to change a formatting flag to tell it that you don't want the characters to overhang the bounding box.  In particular, [StringFormatFlagsNoFitBlackBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) looks useful.

If you were working in straight GDI, you'd probably need to call [GetCharABCWidths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to figure out if and how much the character can overhang the measured bounding box and adjust it manually.